# Pulling items on an RSS feed based on their published date

Tags: php, rss

I'm pulling RSS Feeds from the BBC Sport Website which is displaying items like this:

```
<item> 
  <title>VIDEO: Warnock on why he left Leeds</title>  
  <description>Dan Walker is joined for this week's Focus Forum by Neil Warnock, who discusses his departure from Leeds United earlier this month.</description>  
  <link>http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/22136090</link>  
  <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/22136090</guid>  
  <pubDate>Tue, 16 Apr 2013 08:27:55 GMT</pubDate>  
  <media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/66985000/png/_66985898_warnock.png"/>  
  <media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/66985000/png/_66985900_warnock.png"/> 
</item>
```

I only want to pull the items that have been published 7 days before. So far I have:

```
<?php
  $cnt=0;
foreach($rss->channel->item as $item){
    if ($cnt==100) {
      break;
    }
foreach($rss->entry as $item) {
   if ($item->published) > "") {
  print_r($item);
   }
?>
```

Very unsure about the second foreach, searched this website page to page to find an answer but no luck!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the value in the RSS feed to a DateTime object, and use the comparitor then

Look at Example#2 here:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php